# Pass plan_id into params with submit button

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby, forms

I need to have two submit buttons in one form. The first one also needs to pass plan_id params with it. So basically I need this in my controller params `"plan_id"=>"3"`. Right now my submit button looks like this `<%= f.submit "Select", class: "button-big reverse-blue", name: "plan_id", value: "1" %>` This does not work, if I put a pry in the create action I have no params for plan id. My question is this, how can I pass the plan_id of 1 into the form submit button?

### HTML

```
      <label>
        <%= f.submit "Select", class: "button-big reverse-blue", name: "plan_id", value: "1" %>
      </label>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why don't you use an hidden field in your form for that? Something like

```
<%= f.hidden_field :plan_id, value: plan_id %>
```

Comment: Hmm. I'm not sure how I would set it to that value. Do you know how I could do that?

Answer (score 1):

Add a hidden_field within the form_for and name it `plan_id`, with the `value : 1`.  The form is what passes the parameters, the button just submits them.

`<%= f.hidden_field :plan_id, value: 1 %>`  should be close.

Comment: I see what your saying. But, I don't always want the plan_id to be 1. Only if the user selects the particular submit button that is tied to the free plan. Otherwise I want the page to render the partial for payment details.

Comment: I think @ursus has it